# What is the mapping for array of arrays in elasticsearch 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In ElasticSearch 2.3, I am planning to store data for a field in this way:

```
"pair_age": [
   [12, 19], [17,20], [34,35]
 ]
```

So in mapping how to set it:

```
"pair_age":  { "type":  "????" }
```

What should I set the value of `????` above?

Comment: Since that is called "pair" do you need the association between 12 and 19 for example? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I may not be able to give you the exact context due to IP issue. But think it as husband-wife age pair. I have thought about saving it as nested object, but that is not an option here. So I specifically need array of arrays

Comment: If you cannot use `nested`, then the association will be lost. That array of arrays is like a flat array in the end, no association.

Comment: I can use anything except nested. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use individual documents each with one pair. Or, if you know how many pair will be in this document, define fields for each as static fields.